# Why does the structure not initialize beyond first element?

Tags: c, loops, struct

I am trying to create an fcfs algorithm in C. So I was trying out structures to hold the process. When i try to initialize the structure it is only completing the first iteration. During the second iteration the program gets terminated before completion. Even the display function has that issue (but it displays 3 iterations). I am not able to understand why.

```
struct proc{
    int id;
    int arrivalt;
    int burstt;
    int compt;
    int turnt;
    int waitt;
    bool completed;
};
void initialize(struct proc* x[],int n){
    int i;
    printf("n-%d\n",n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Entered\n");
        printf("id - %d\n",x[i]->id);
        x[i]->id=0;
        printf("new id-%d\n",x[i]->id);
        x[i]->arrivalt=0;
        x[i]->burstt=0;
        x[i]->compt=0;
        x[i]->turnt=0;
        x[i]->waitt=0;
        x[i]->completed=false;
    }
    return;
}
int main(){
    int n,i;
    struct proc *x[20];
    printf("Enter n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    initialize(x,n);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Enter n4
n-4
Entered
id - 56824
new id-0
Entered
id - 1220774728

--------------------------------
Process exited after 1.282 seconds with return value 3221225477
Press any key to continue . . .
```

display function called out

```
Enter n5
id      arrival burst   completion      turnaround      waiting
6702    972062720       0       0       0       0
1220774728      1076124811      611617608       2089502792      -1957933020     1213736036
686588744       889555784       1207959565      -2058878837     -14846784       93014224

--------------------------------
Process exited after 2.472 seconds with return value 3221225477
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: `struct proc *x[20];` is an array of pointers to struct, but no memory was allocated.

Comment: How do i allocate that?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { x[i] = malloc(sizeof *x[i]); }`

Comment: It's unclear that you *need* an array of pointers. Did you intend it to be an array of `struct`?

Comment: using `struct proc x[20];` would be better/easier IMO

Comment: and then the function can be `void initialize(struct proc x[], int n)`

Comment: Yeah I forgot that array is passed as pointer.